# ng-class multiple class conditions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have list of categories with depth level 3 so every level have class but when I select level 3 category with "**cat**" style I need add "**active**" class to li element but don't have a clue how to add multiple conditions to ng-class modlue I tried this way and some other ways but with no luck I just need to append active class to li element of clicked link??

```
<li ng-repeat="category in categories track by category.id" ng-class="{1: 'root', 2: 'sub', 3: 'cat'}[category.depth] || {cActive: 'active'}[category.id]">
  <a ng-click="setCategory(category.id)">{{category.title}}</a>
</li>
```

and here is my scope function

```
$scope.setCategory = function ($category.id) {
    $scope.cActive = $category.id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-class` expects an object, and what your syntax is doing is trying to merge two strings with an `||` operator. That won't work.

Here is how you could use `ng-class` correctly:

```
ng-class="{root: category.depth === 1,
           sub:  category.depth === 2,
           cat:  category.depth === 3,
           active: cActive === category.id}"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply I tried this way too it works with active categories but i just get one value true and other are false I need 2 values to be true to get "**cat active**" this way I just get "**active**" to true other values are ignored

Comment: @NeoNe What is the actual type of `category.depth`? Is it a string, or a number?

Comment: ooow thats why it wasn't working it was a string I added '1' to a numbers and it works now thank you a loot :) :) :)